# How do I prompt a user to import their yahoo contacts list upon clicking a form?

Tags: php, yahoo-api

I am trying to have a user sign up for a service via a PHP form and upon successful validation of their yahoo email prompt them to allow my application access to their contacts list (i.e. import the list) and ask them to send a message to their contacts.

Unfortunately I don't really know where to start, the code samples on the yahoo site itself are a little bit too advanced and not direct enough.

Can someone point me to a similar code sample or sketch out quasi-code? I want to actually learn how to do this...so i don't want ready made scripts to download...unless they are a tutorial/other pedagogical resource...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can start [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/social/contacts/) (official)
2. But this is the best I found so far [Grab Yahoo!](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3127-PHP-Grab-the-contact-list-calendar-of-an-Yahoo-user.html) at phpclasses.org..  (you need to be a registered user to access file). There are download links at the bottom of page.
3. Try keywords like ["php grab yahoo contacts" in Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=php%20grab%20yahoo%20contacts) for more solutions.